# How can I find dice shops?

Tags: dice

Is there an online resource that lets me find places where I can get dice? I'm currently in Germany, but an international resource would be good too. By places, I mean physical shops - not a list of web pages.

It doesn't have to be a list of shops that sell just dice - anywhere that has, amongst other products, the usual range of 7 dice would make me happy.

Comment: So you're looking for a list of brick and mortar dice shops, or a site that has that list?

Comment: @Phil If this were a question for a list of German brick-and-mortar dice shops, that'd be off-topic for at least two reasons, so definitely a site with a list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In most countries, finding an actual *roleplaying game* shop („Rollenspiel-Shop“) specifically is usually pretty hit-and-miss, though worth trying as a first pass. To find a polyhedral dice supplier you often have better luck by doing a second pass looking for boardgame („Brettspiel“) and hobby retailers, to expand your sources.

Then, armed with a list of local shops, you dial 'em up and ask about their stock.

To do the searching, your best bets are Germany's equivalent to the *Yellow Pages*, [Gelbe Seiten](http://www.gelbeseiten.de/)*, and the localised version of [Google Maps](http://maps.google.de/).

<sup>* Hat tip to [nvoigt](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31083/how-can-i-find-dice-shops#comment61236_31083) for the link.</sup>

Comment: Other places I have had good luck with are Newsagents (Got my first dice from one, they kept a box behind the counter), and Educational Suppliers (they use them to teach math, I got very cheap dice there).